# How to only use Android 21 in all app dependencies?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to ONLY target Android Lollipop (21) for app development but Android Studio seems to force me download and install all the latest tools up to Android Oreo (28). Some of the information was removed for brevity. Let me know if you need to know anything else.

## App Gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
dependencies{
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:21.0.0'
}
```

## Project Gradle

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

Errors that I have been getting,

`ERROR: Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.0.2`

`Google Play requires that apps target API level 26 or higher.` <= at `targetSdkVersion`

As of now I am trying to reinstall Android Studio

Comment: `I want to ONLY target Android Lollipop (21)` Why you want to targetSdkVersion 21 and Also read this [Meet Google Play's target API level requirement](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk)

Comment: @NileshRathod so that I do not accidentally used newer versions' functionalities. I also do not intend to use Google Play services.

Comment: @dude Then you use minSDKVersion=21.  That's enough to see errors when you use higher versions.  You wouldn't use targetSDKVersion=21.  Also note that the Play Store does not accept apps with targetSDK <26 anymore.  So unless this is a personal app or distributed by another channel, you don't want to do this

Comment: @GabeSechan, setting minSDKVersion=21 won't necessarily give you errors when you use higher version functionality - instead compatibility libraries will get added to the app causing its size to increase dramatically. This makes it tricky to develop personal apps for an old API 21 device with limited memory.

Comment: @Ovaflo No, you're absolutely wrong there.  If you use an API added in a higher api (lets say 23) to a api 21 app, it will crash when run on an API 21 app.  Now for some classes they add backwards compatible versions of classes that add functionality, but those libraries don't magically get added or used-  you have to use them explicitly.

Comment: @GabeSechan, my experience is that I have had to explicitly remove such libraries in the past. I don't know what action I took that caused them to be added, but I didn't explicitly add them. Maybe some GUI actions might trigger this, whereas pure coding probably won't.

Comment: @GabeSechan, it appears that some libraries (com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0, etc.) get added when a new project is created, regardless of the chosen minimum API (21 or 28), so apparently there's no way around manually removing them if you don't want the bloat. But I get the feeling that those libraries only add new classes (widgets, themes, and the like) and don't exactly fake a higher API level, so maybe you're right that I'm wrong. :-)

Comment: @Ovaflo You can remove them by removing them from your gradle file.  They don't fake a higher API level, but they do sometimes provide support for functions added in higher api levels to their versions of the classes and by using those classes instead you can get the function backported effectively.  But they don't have to add any bloat-  a standard proguard file will remove any class not directly accessed in your app (unless you access it via reflection, in which case you'll need a custom proguard file).

Comment: @GabeSechan, the libraries don't get optimized away, because they are used by the boilerplate code generated by Android Studio , so the trick is to replace all references to the libraries with alternatives that are built into the OS (e.g. native themes and widgets instead of new fancy ones), and *then* remove the libraries from the gradle file.

Comment: @Ovaflo They get optimized awy if you put in the right proguard file-  proguard can remove individual classes from libraries based on use.  Android studio's boilerplate can all be deleted if you want.  No offense, but it seems like you only have half a handle on how things actually work. And really you DONT want to do what you just suggested-  you can, but you open yourself up to a bunch of compatibility bugs on different versions.

Comment: @GabeSechan, I understand what you're saying, but like the OP I'm writing only for API 21, so all the compatibility stuff is a waste of memory. For apps going to a broader audience my approach is of course a no go.

Comment: @Ovaflo No, it isn't. The compatibility stuff also had bug fixers that ensure things actually work the same across all devices. Remember that there is no way for the user, or Google, to patch bugs in the framework. They can update the compatibility library. That's half the point of it

Comment: @Ovaflo Besides which, unless you're writing only for your own personal device and never plan on updating, you're never writing for just one API level.  You're writing for an API minimum.  The devices that it runs on will be that level AND HIGHER.  Which  means that function foo() may behave differently, due to bug or decision, on a device running API 23 vs 21.  This has happened many, many times in the past.

Comment: @GabeSechan, everything you're saying is true, but the OP's question is about writing for API 21 only, and my comments only apply to that narrow scenario, which happens to be one I have worked within for years when writing personal apps for my own device and wanting to keep the apk sizes to the bare minimum. If memory is not an issue for you (or compatibility is), there is no reason to do what I described.

Comment: @Ovaflo Anyone who actually talked him into backing himself into a corner like that with no way to port his apps off, for the savings of a minimum amount of storage which is close to 0 if you know how to correctly write a proguard file, is doing a grave professional disservice to him.  Just because you can do something doesn't mean you should.  Nothing you suggested should ever be done.

Comment: @GabeSechan, I get the feeling that I'm not quite getting my point across. I'm not talking about removing unused elements in a library. Proguard will do that. But it won't remove stuff that is in use (that would break the app) - you need to manually replace code and resources that take up space in the app with ones that don't (as they're located outside the app). And the goal is to minimize the apk footprint. Not for professional app development, but certainly worth considering for squeezing an extra homemade app into your own phone.